# How to wait for multiple parallel tasks to all finish first to proceed to next state in AWS Step Function?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-step-functions

I'm trying to build a process like this:
In state1, it will trigger 10 lambdas, and only when **ALL** those 10 lambda respond/ or call callback with taskToken, it will then proceed to next state2.
How to design this process?

Comment: Have you tried "Parallel" state to run multiple lambda function in parallel & wait for all of them to complete before moving to the next state?

Comment: Parallel or Map, depending on the specifics of the use case.  Parallel for "trigger 10 different Lambda functions".  Map for "trigger a single Lambda function 10 times, optionally with different payloads".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a perfect scenario for the [Map state](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/step-functions/latest/dg/amazon-states-language-map-state.html). You can pass in an array of lambda function names, then add a Lambda task and use the Parameters block to set the function dynamically. And if you want them to run one at a time instead of in parallel, you can set MaxConcurrency.